# "Location" vs. "locality"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, confusables, when

I can't seem to find a good explanation of what the differences are between the words *location* and *locality*. Are they interchangeable, or are there certain contexts in which one or the other must be used?

Comment: I'd have thought any dictionary would make this clear. The *location* of something means *exactly where it is*, whereas the *locality* means *the general region around where it is*.

Comment: I think that e.g. in the sense of computer science terms like "locality of reference", *locality* also has a meaning like "property of remaining localized", i.e. unmoving.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Actually, "locality" and "localized" in that context don't mean "unmoving" but "within a specific region". For example, "locality of reference" means many references in a small region.

Answer (score 4):

It's all about knowing that location refers to a specific position on the map (the degree of certainty of the location can vary enormously depending on the context, from a specific coordinate in the map (*What's your location? 38° 41' 7.8351", longitude: -96° 30' 14.0625"*)) to an entire continent *What's your location? Europe*) while *locality* will almost always refer to a specific town, village or area.

In general terms *location* is to *position* as *locality* is to *village/town/area*.

They are usually not interchangeable but since *location* is more general than *locality*, *locality* could be replaced by *location* in the right context.

Besides, since *localities* refer to predefined areas, they usually have names.

> What is your (current) location?
>   My (current) location is latitude: 38° 41' 7.8351", longitude: -96° 30' 14.0625".

There is no need to be so specific, you could also say:

> I'm near the river.
>
> I'm almost there.
>
> Home.
>
> Europe.

Regarding *locality*:

> On what village/locality are you in?
>   I'm in Springfield.

If it was common for the operator to travel from village to village in a short period of time, village/locality would turn redundant and location could also be used.

> What's your location?
>   Springfield.

Comment: Is it possible to refer to a big city (like Madrid) as "locality"?

Answer (score 0):

Location indicates the exact location, a position of something and locality indicates a small area of a country, city etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Location** is a place - a particular place, especially in relation to other areas - where something exists or happens.

> His apartment is in a really good location

A **locality**  denotes the fact or condition of having a location in space or time.

> ... weather reports from several different localities