# Is the expression "the location of a previous bench" correct?

Tags: word-usage

So I've been correcting an architectural piece translated into English, wherein a sentence befuddles me:

> ...A wooden table... marked the location of a previous bench.

What the author tried to say is that a wooden table is now located where once stood a bench. This usage of *previous* simply doesn't feel right to me. Any advice?

PS, what about *location* in that sentence? For me, if a noun has to be used,  *locality* seems to work better in the sense of "the fact or condition of having a location or position in space" of the word. Or am I over-scrutinizing things here?

Comment: Sounds fine to me the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, *locality* conveys a general area, rather than a specific location as previously explained [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57764/location-vs-locality), so *location* is the better word in this context.

*Previous* is OK in that context, but I agree that it doesn't "feel" right.  I would maybe use *earlier*, or rewrite the phrase entirely as *A wooden table...marked the location where a bench once stood*.